# How do I get the ID of a view automatically using formulas and functions?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I need to generate a `URL` to be sent by `email to outlook`, I include the ID of view

```
notes://server/86257DCD007397AD/0/0B8975124263A97086257F8B00734863
```

Answer (score 1):

The UNID of a view is not available in Lotus @formulas, but you can use @ViewTitle, which gives you the name. You can use the name in URLs instead of the UNID. That way your link will work even if the database has to be replaced with a new non-replica copy at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use NotesView's property **.UniversalID** to get view's id:

```
Set view = db.GetView("YourViewName")
id = view.UniversalID
```

in *LotusScript*.

Use **.getUniversalID()** in *Java*:

```
View view = db.getView("YourViewName");
String id = view.getUniversalID();
```